# Compilation errors using JHipster on OSX and ojdbc; has anyone had any run in with this and got past it?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

This is the compilation errors I get when running ./mvnw on osx with JHipster configured for an OJDBC connection:
[image]

This is what shows up in addition when running ./mvn -X:
[image]

Comment: Don't know why you get corrupted jars,you must clean them https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html About Oracle driver, I don't know why you had to install ojdbc7 manually because since one month Oracle driver is available on maven central https://medium.com/oracledevs/oracle-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-central-64fcf724d8b

Comment: Also you use jdk 11 but odjbc7 is not supported for it, you should consider following Oracle's recommendations https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html#01_01 and if you are stuck with an old version you should use JDK 8